# Sqlite Database is locked error 5 when used insert or update query?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety

I have create database class which have all operation CRUD. i have read successfully all database whenever once time insert or update query fire perfectly done after that insert or update query won't work but it's read all data sucessfully.

I have already used singleton but it's not work.

```
 -(MyClass *)sharedInstance
 {
    static MyClass *sharedInstance=nil;
    static  dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
     });
return sharedInstance;
 }
```

because of multi-thread issue but it's not work.

My insert function

```
- (NSNumber *) insertRow:(NSDictionary *) record
 {
   int dictionarySize = [record count];

NSMutableData *dKeys = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizeof(id) *dictionarySize];

NSMutableData * dValues = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: sizeof(id) * dictionarySize];
[record getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dValues.mutableBytes andKeys:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dKeys.mutableBytes];

NSMutableArray *placeHoldersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dictionarySize];

for (int count = 0 ; count < dictionarySize ; count++)
    [placeHoldersArray addObject:@"?"];

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",tableName,[[record allKeys]componentsJoinedByString:@","],[placeHoldersArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

[self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];

sqlite3_step(statment);

if(sqlite3_finalize(statment) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    return [self lastInsertId];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"doQuery: sqlite3_finalize failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    return @0;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Show the code with the error.

Comment: call sqlite3_finalize and sqlite3_close after completing the transactions. If it is multi-thread issue use @synchronized for making it thread safe.

Comment: i put my insert code @trojanfoe

Comment: OK so you need to know if sqlite was compiled with multi-threading support or not (not sure if the stock iOS version is).  If not you need to lock around database accesses as the singleton pattern has nothing to do with thread safety of the use of the object.

Comment: how to open database open globally because i  open & close database at every function. that's may be multi-thrading problem. @trojanfoe

Comment: Well you shouldn't be doing that either; close it when the app goes into the background otherwise leave it open all the time.  This will make the app more responsive.

Comment: You *must provide your own synchronization* when using SQLite in a multi-threaded environment.  If it's compiled with the right options it will fail with the above error if you attempt "simultaneous" operations, but that's as good as it gets.  And, of course, you must finalize compiled queries and end started transactions appropriately.  (Closing after every transaction, though, is a waste.)

Comment: all the time leave it open the database it's giving me 21 error @trojanfoe

Comment: 21 = `SQLITE_MISUSE`.  Closing the database to solve that is avoiding the issue.

Comment: when i open database at first time it's insert function work perfect.but after that insert function not work. i put Log for open and close database. open and close database work perfectly? why Error 5 is coming @trojanfoe

Comment: You get the errors because you're not doing the right sequence.  It's hard to guess what's wrong with the above code since we don't see `bindSQL`.